# WPF How can I bind a Grid's row to another row?

Tags: wpf

I got here two User Controls, I want FourSeventh's Grid.Row property to be bound to FourEighth's Grid.Row property in xaml, but how?

Here are my xaml

```
<dims:ToothControl x:Name="FourEighth" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />

<dims:ToothControl x:Name="FourSeventh" Grid.Row="{Binding Path=FourEighth}" Grid.Column="1"  /> <--error here-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind using **`ElementName`** and since **`Grid.Row`** is an attached property, you have to use paranthesis:

```
<dims:ToothControl x:Name="FourSeventh"
                   Grid.Row="{Binding (Grid.Row), ElementName=FourEighth}" 
                   Grid.Column="1"/>
```